# Current isolation level in oracle

Tags: oracle, transaction

How to get the current (default) transaction isolation level in oracle?

Comment: If you're looking for the current isolation level of a session, see this SO question: [How can you see what transaction isolation level an arbitrary oracle session is using.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3663343/119634)

Comment: Are you looking for the default isolation level for transactions in a session or the isolation level of the current transaction in progress?

Answer (score 7):

Using the query from the SO answer Vincent Malgrat referenced, here is how you can get the transaction isolation level for the transaction in progress:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#,
   CASE BITAND(t.flag, POWER(2, 28))
      WHEN 0 THEN 'READ COMMITTED'
      ELSE 'SERIALIZABLE'
   END AS isolation_level
FROM v$transaction t 
JOIN v$session s ON t.addr = s.taddr AND s.sid = sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

If you are not already in a transaction you can start one with the following:

```
declare 
   trans_id Varchar2(100);
begin
   trans_id := dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id( TRUE );
end;
/
```

It seems like there would be an easier way than this.  I don't know how to get the default isolation level for the session if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I am using something like:

```
with q1 as (
select distinct name, isdefault, value
,decode(value,'serializable',SID,null) SID 
from V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV 
where lower(name) like '%isolation%' order by name
)
select q1.*
,vs.status,vs.username,vs.OSUSER,vs.MACHINE,vs.TERMINAL,vs.PROGRAM
from q1, v$session vs
where q1.sid=vs.sid(+);
```